# Jquery plugin for rotation and resize image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, resize, rotation

I'm looking for a jquery plugin for resizing and rotate an image. 
With my research I have found this one witch is excatly what I want to do but it doesn't work in IE.
http://vremenno.net/examples/jquery-ui-rotation/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you can do [rotation with CSS](http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate), and you can resize images just with an the `height` and `width` attributes (or with CSS's `height` and `width` properties). As you can read on the linked article, IE is always finicky about stuff like rotations, so it doesn't surprise me that the jQuery plugin in question has some trouble with IE.

Comment: I can't use CSS because I need to allow the user to chose the exact angle that he want and get this information to built a new image with PHP

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a new batch image resizing tool called sizzlepig? It is not a plugin, it is web based. You can not rotate your images with the tool (which seems like a big priority) and from your second comment it sounds like the end user will be interacting with this, rather than you just doing production work. Anyway, you can batch resize tons of images at once and can also crop and scale. Hope this helps.